# AngularJs How to change CallBack Function based on Watch Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, watch

I have a directive in angular "spyStyle"
And I'd like to make it as usable as possible.
So... I'd like to be able to call different callback functions based on what is being watched.

Here is my code

```
.directive('spyStyle', [function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return element.css(attrs['spyAttribute']);
                }, styleChangedCallBack, true);

                function styleChangedCallBack(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                        // do something interesting here
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Comment: Pass in the value being watched, pass in the callback.

Comment: thank you tymeJV , from how I solved it below, is that a proper way of handling things? It seems I shouldn't have to write the entire scope.$watch statement twice only to call a separate callback function
Couldn't I just set a variable of which callback function to use and pass that to the $scope.watch statement? Because when I tried it that way, I received an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has done it -- I have to run the if statement BEFORE the watch function.
Does anyone else have another suggestion???

```
                if ((attrs['spyAttribute']) = 'background-color') {
                    alert("background-color");
                    scope.$watch(function () {
                        element.css('color', 'black');
                        return element.css(attrs['spyAttribute']);
                    }, bgStyleChangedCallBack, true);
                } else {
                    alert("something else");
                    scope.$watch(function () {
                        //element.css('color', 'black');
                        return element.css(attrs['spyAttribute']);
                    }, styleChangedCallBack, true);
                }
```

Here is the full code https://jsfiddle.net/acts7/5Ls46ebx/

The full directive checks the background color of an element and changes text to become readable. 
It then checks if the background color changes, and applies new text color if necessary.